# Using Selected Value from a slicer within a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm in need of some help.

First let me outline the data.

I have 2 columns Product & Days until Expiry date

I also have a calculated column which uses a switch statement that looks at the Days until Expiry date column and and assigns labels e.g. if the Product has more than 100 days until expiry then it will be assigned the label "No Orders required"

Current Code

```
ProductLabels =
SWITCH (
    TRUE(),
    isblank('DF'[Days until Expiry date]),"No Date available",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]>=100, "No Orders required",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]<100 "Orders Required"
)
```

The issue is that this month we might label products with < 100 days until expiry as "Orders Required" and next month this might be pushed to < 150 days

I want to create a slicer which will have 100,150,200,250 days. when the user selects one I want the calculated column above to be dynamically adjusted.

e.g. it will look like this

```
ProductLabels =
VAR SV = SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[Values])
SWITCH (
TRUE(),
    isblank('DF'[Days until Expiry date]),"No Date available",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]>=SV , "No Orders required",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]<SV ,"Orders Required"
)
```

And the final result will be a distinct count of the products by label

e.g

| Label | Distinct Count of Products |
| --- | --- |
| No Change | 10 |
| Orders Required | 20 |
| No Orders Required | 30 |

I'm aware that selectedvalue cannot be used within calculated columns so I'm looking to create a measure that contains a distinct count.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Have you tried after creating a table, specifically for slicer?

Comment: @Sam_Shri I have, this outlined as a variable above "VAR SV = SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[Values])"

Answer (score 0):

If I took your question correctly then you could try below code:-

```
ProductLabels =
VAR SV = int(SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[Values]))
SWITCH (
TRUE(),
    isblank('DF'[Days until Expiry date]),"No Date available",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]>=SV , "No Orders required",
    'DF'[Days until Expiry date]<SV ,"Orders Required"
)
```

Comment: thank you for the solution but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I pick a specific number of days on the slicer e.g. 200 nothing happens